# User feature export display errors

Tags: 8, drush

I am getting errors once export user feature. I have just export and put inside my module folder.

Drush show below error:

> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException: The service "ctools.serializable.tempstore.factory" has a dependency on a non-existent parameter "user.tempstore.expire". in /var/www/html/project/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ParameterBag/ParameterBag.php on line 84 #0